# Why can't Pug iterate through some of my arrays/objects that came from a child template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pug, javascript-objects

So I have a file called base-default.pug, which sets up my head and body tag. I have a file that extends it called index.pug. It only contains two Javascript objects:

localHeadProps: an object of information for head tag specific to index.html which I want to generate
scriptPaths: an array of relative paths to script file to include at the bottom of the body tag.

When I try using an each...in loop for localHeadProps it works, but for scriptPaths I get an error saying it's undefined. This is odd because using `!{scriptPaths}` outputs the contents just fine, so how can it be undefined?

Can someone explain why each...in loop only works for localHeadProps in base-default.pug, but not for scriptPaths or any other array/object I put in index.pug?

What is odd is that in order for it to work, I have to precede it with an if statement checking that it exists, or use a Javascript for...in loop. However, I still don't understand why I have to resort to these hacks.

index.pug

```
extend base-pages/base-default

block localVariables
  -
    //- page-specific head configurations
    const localHeadProps = {
      title: "Best Note Taking App - Organize Your Notes with Evernote",
      description: "Our note taking app helps you capture and prioritize ideas, projects and to-do lists, so nothing falls through the cracks. Start your free trial today!",
      keywords: "HTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript",
      stylesheetPaths: [
        "css/styles.min.css",
      ]
    };
    const scriptPaths = [
      "js/bundle.js",
      "js/vendor.js",
    ];
```

base-default.pug

```
include ../abstracts/variables
include layout/head

block localVariables

doctype html
html(lang="en")
  +head(globalHeadProps, localHeadProps)
  body
    h1 Hello Base Page
    //- outputs <p>scriptPaths: js/bundle.js,js/vendor.js</p>
    p scriptPaths: !{scriptPaths}

    //- this doesn't work
    each scriptPath in scriptPaths
      script(src=scriptPath)

    //- this actually works
    each item in localHeadProps
      p=item
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update pug to the latest version.
I successfully compiled your templates with pug v.2.0.4 and pug-cli v1.0.0-alpha6.

Moreover, i assume that you are not altering `scriptPaths` variable inside the `head` mixin.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm using gulp-pug v.4.0.1 which depends on pug v.2.0.3 so I'm wondering if it only works for that 2.0.4

Comment: @Deluxateer did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, as I'm not really keeping up with the issue anymore. Thank you for your help!